# Opentok Video is not working using Firefox Version 57.0.1

Tags: angularjs, node.js, browser, opentok

I am using open.min.js v2 with node and angular It is perfectly working fine in on Chrome latest version but not Firefox v57.0.1.

Here's the errors I'm seeing in console:

```
OT.Publisher.onStreamAvailableError OT_MEDIA_ERR_ABORTED: Unknown error while getting user media: InternalError

OT.exception :: title: Unable to Publish (1500) msg: GetUserMedia
```

I'm using following code:-

```
 session.connect(token, function (error) {
        if (error) {
          if (error.name === "OT_NOT_CONNECTED") {
            videocall_err.innerHTML = 'You are not connected to the internet. Check your network connection.';
          }
        } else {

          var publisherProperties = {
            width: 200,
            height: 150,
            name: result.data.user.fullname
          };
          publisher = OT.initPublisher('myPublisherDiv', publisherProperties);

          session.publish(publisher).on("streamDestroyed", function (event) {
          event.preventDefault();

          if (event.reason == 'networkDisconnected') {
            console.log("networkDisconnected");
          }
          });

        }
      });
      session.on("sessionDisconnected", function (event) {

      });
 });
```

Comment: I'm successfully using opentok with Firefox57. Please provide the code you're using to create your publisher, this is likely causing the issue.

Comment: Please see the above editing in my question @aiham

Comment: I copy and pasted your code into https://output.jsbin.com/rijured and I'm able to get access to the camera/microphone on Firefox 58. Does this jsbin work for you?